# I just read about a house that had a "busybody" What is a busybody?

Tags: meaning

I was reading O'hara's *10 North Frederick* and in describing a house he mentions a dumb-waiter, a speaking tube and a "busybody." What exactly is a busybody?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=define+busybody Look at the dictionary entries, if you still don't understand, please edit your question explaining "why".

Comment: @Mari-LouA The only definition that pops up _everywhere_ is along the lines of _a person who is too interested in the private lives of other people_, which seems strange to include in a list of properties of a house. Maybe this question is about the context, or maybe the OP would like to know if there is another, possibly more obscure or obsolete meaning of the word _busybody_ that would fit more with the service-elevator and the communication system that are mentioned...

Comment: @oerkelens please see deadrat's answer. I have only ever heard of a "busybody" as someone who doesn't mind their own business, the same one reported in dictionaries.

Answer (score 51):

From the printed supplement to the *OED*:

> **busybody**.... a mirror attached to a building, reflecting a view of the street, etc. *U.S.*

[image]

Comment: Well, I never...  http://www.kilianhardware.com/franbus.html

Comment: Does that device go by another name? Looking it up by "busybody" seems impossible

Comment: @Saebekassebil - Traffic and/or secure mirror.

Comment: @Saebekassebil aka Franklin busybody mirror.

Comment: in Danish these are called "gadespejl", lit. "street mirror". But my dictionary suggests "window mirror"

Comment: @Wad: a *traffic mirror* would be one positioned so that cars or pedestrians could see cars or pedestrians. I suspect most busybodys are positioned so you can see who's at your door, so *secure mirror* would be the correct alternate name.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Trust me, I’m as astounded as you must be.

Comment: @PeterShor Traffic; noun: trade; buying and selling; commercial dealings. A traffic mirror would be one to see who is at your door, presumably for commercial dealings (door to door salesmen, deliveries, etc.)

Comment: @PeterShor - that should have said "security mirror"

Comment: @corsiKa: One of the first instances of *"traffic mirror"* in [Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=ImofAQAAMAAJ&q=%22traffic+mirror%22&dq=%22traffic+mirror%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAmoVChMI1uq88tifxwIVAgo-Ch3sXAB7) (from 1914) is the caption: *"A traffic mirror erected by the Hampshire Automobile Club at a dangerous comer at Hythe. The reflection seen in the mirror on the right is that of a car approaching from the road on the left."*

Comment: @Saebekassebil They are? I didn't realise they were called _anything_ in Danish—I've never even heard of the concept. _Gadespejl_ is something different to me (a traffic mirror, as per Peter’s explanation above).

Comment: Wow, we learn something every day.

Answer (score 2):

The "Philadelphia Busy Body" was common on houses 100-200 years ago.  The series of mirrors allowed the lady of the house to see a street vendor coming down the street and stop him with his cart.  If she didn't see the street vendor he would pass by her house and continue on. She might not get her fruits and vegetables for that day

Answer (score 0):

> [busybody](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/busybody)
>
> A meddling or prying person
>
> SYNONYMS: [informal] *snoop, snooper, looky-loo, nosy parker*
>
> <sup>Oxford Dictionaries</sup>

or a device for that purpose.

Comment: What is the GT for? Please quote things that you are quoting (by prefacing them with >) and properly reference where you got them from.

Comment: -1. This is not the meaning that the author of O'hara's _10 North Frederick_ meant. You meant well, though.

Comment: Technically the correct answer does fit the "or a device for that purpose" part of this answer.